# Why Regular Expression is not working correctly?

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to solve [Valid Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/) problem on **leetcode**. My choice of language for this problem is Java.

Here is the problem statement if you do not wish to visit website.

### Problem Statement

A **valid number** can be split up into these components (in order):

1. A decimal number or an integer.
2. (Optional) An 'e' or 'E', followed by an integer.

A **decimal number** can be split up into these components (in order):

1. (Optional) A sign character (either '+' or '-').
2. One of the following formats:

   1. At least one digit, followed by a dot '.'.
   2. At least one digit, followed by a dot '.', followed by at least one digit.
   3. A dot '.', followed by at least one digit.

An **integer** can be split up into these components (in order):

1. (Optional) A sign character (either '+' or '-').
2. At least one digit.

For example, all the following are valid numbers:

`["2", "0089", "-0.1", "+3.14", "4.", "-.9", "2e10", "-90E3", "3e+7", "+6e-1", "53.5e93", "-123.456e789"]`

while the following are not valid numbers:

`["abc", "1a", "1e", "e3", "99e2.5", "--6", "-+3", "95a54e53"]`

Given a string s, return true if `s` is a valid number.

### My Approach

I tried to match the given string against the following regular expression.

> `((\\+|-)?(\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d)[eE]?)`

I analysed the whole regular expression on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) in Javascript. It's working fine in Javascript when I check it against inputs. I just simply *escaped* the escape character `\` to make my regular expression work in Java.

> Regular Expression in Javascript :- `/\+|-?(\d*\.\d+|\d)[eE]?/g`

Below is the whole code :-

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isNumber(String s) {
        String regex = "((\\+|-)?(\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d)[eE]?)";
        return s.matches(regex);
    }
}
```

But it's giving me wrong answer. Can someone please help ?

I'd like to understand why the Java version of this regular expression isn't working ?

I could look at the leetcode discuss section to find an answer, but I'd like an explanation on whats exactly wrong with the Java Version of regular expression.

Comment: Are you sure you have `/\+|-?(\d*\.\d+|\d)[eE]?/g` in JS? The `\+|-` part is wrong, it must be wrapped with parentheses. Another point: your JS regex is `/.../g`, matching multiple occurrences of a pattern anywhere in the string while in Java, you are using `.matches()`, a method that requires a full string (single) match. I suspect that is the only real problem: you need to use `Matcher#find` in a loop to get all matches.

Comment: I added the parentheses in Java Version but in JS, I didn't have parentheses and it was working fine. Thanks for pointing out `/.../g`. These are present by default in Regexr website.

Comment: Sorry, but `\+|-?(\d*\.\d+|\d)[eE]?` is NOT working fine in any way. It matches either a `+` char, or an optional `-`, then either zero or more digits + `.` + one or more digit or a single digit and then a `E` or `e`. You say you need "*(Optional) A sign character (either `+` or `-`)*." - that is `[-+]?`. So, you did not actually use the regex in JavaScript, only at the online regex tester with JS option set.

Comment: You need to force 1 or more digits after the [eE] character set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `3e+7` must match but there is nothing after `[eE]` your regex looks wrong.

The following regex pass all given tests:

```
String regex = "^(\\+|\\-)?(\\d+\\.\\d*|\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+)([eE](\\+|\\-)?\\d+)?$";
```

We can read that as:

- `^` must match at begining.
- `(\\+|\\-)?` may be there are `+` or `-`.
- `( decimal1 | decimal2 | integer )` that is, digits dot and maybe more digits, maybe digits dot and digits, only digits.
- `( 10exponent )?` maybe exponent where `10exponent` is `e` followed by maybe sign and an integer.
- `$` nothing more.

Comment: It works fine. But I do not actually need to escape the `-` character, right ? Still, when I escaped it v/s when I didn't, the code ran a little bit faster in former scenario. Can you shed some light on that ?

Comment: @VIVEKJAIN when it's escaped, it's treated as normal char, if not, must to perform a small backtracking when the regex is compiled. If you precompile the regex `Pattern.compile("^(\\+|-)?(\\d+\\.\\d*|\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+)([eE](\\+|-)?\\d+)?$")` the difference go away.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regex to solve it. Try parsing the string using `Double#parseDouble` and if it fails, declare that the string does not represent a number.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "2", "0089", "-0.1", "+3.14", "4.", "-.9", "2e10", "-90E3", "3e+7", "+6e-1", "53.5e93",
                "-123.456e789", "abc", "1a", "1e", "e3", "99e2.5", "--6", "-+3", "95a54e53" };

        for (String s : arr) {
            try {
                double n = Double.parseDouble(s);
                System.out.println(s + " => " + n);
            } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(s + " is not a valid number.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 => 2.0
0089 => 89.0
-0.1 => -0.1
+3.14 => 3.14
4. => 4.0
-.9 => -0.9
2e10 => 2.0E10
-90E3 => -90000.0
3e+7 => 3.0E7
+6e-1 => 0.6
53.5e93 => 5.35E94
-123.456e789 => -Infinity
abc is not a valid number.
1a is not a valid number.
1e is not a valid number.
e3 is not a valid number.
99e2.5 is not a valid number.
--6 is not a valid number.
-+3 is not a valid number.
95a54e53 is not a valid number.
```

Note that `"NaN"`, `"Infinity"`, `"0xap0"` etc. are also valid numbers. Check [Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) to learn more about it.

Comment: Can you shed some more light on the internal working of the `Double#parseDuble` method and also explain why `"NaN"`, `"Infinity"` and `"0xap0"` will get accepted as well ?

Comment: @VIVEKJAIN - I've updated my answer to add the link to the section in Java Specification which describes it.

Comment: The java language specification is not the specification of `Double#parseDouble` - although the method is compliant.